# Failed to start monitoring 09768fb90408

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, adb, flutter-dependencies

I have two flutter project in android studio.
in one of the project when I trying to generate the release build
it is giving

```
Failed to start monitoring 09768fb90408
```

But in another project it is getting generated with out any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing same issues.
Instead of generating build from Android studio
Generate through terminal
Open terminal and fire these two command

```
flutter clean
```

And than

```
flutter build apk ---release
```

Comment: Hi  @arunaditya thank you for answering this hack is working and now I am able to generate the build but do you know how can I generate through android studio.